# Trouble trying to prove $f(n)= n.1_R$ is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In this link https://yutsumura.com/there-is-exactly-one-ring-homomorphism-from-the-ring-of-integers-to-any-ring/
it is proven that there is a unique homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to any ring R. But I think only uniqueness is proven and not existence, they just declare that $f(n)= n.1_R$ is a ring homomorphism which is the most difficult and it seems very long

It looks like I need to define this first:

Let $n.r$ for $r\in R$ and $n \in \mathbb Z$ be a shortcut for

$r+r+...r ...(n $times$)$ if $n>0$

$0$ if $n=0$

$-r -r...-r... (-n $times$)$ if $n<0$

The only straight forward part seems to be $f(1)=1.1_R=1_R$.

In order to prove $f(n+m)=f(n)+f(m)$ and $f(nm)=f(n)f(m)$ it seems like I have to analyse  all 9 possible cases
for all the combinations of $n$ and $m$ being $>0,<0$ or $=0$

I ran into some trouble when trying to prove them. Here I expose two of them:

a. First I proved them for $n,m>0$, no problem there. To prove it for $n,m<0$ it looks like I need first the following property: $f(-a)=-f(a)$ which I tried proving like this:
$0=f(0)=f(a-a)=f(a)+f(-a) \implies f(-a)=-f(a)$, but later realized it was wrong because $f(c+d)=f(c)+f(d)$ only holds for $c,d>0$ so far, and not for $a$ and $-a $that have opposite signs so I can't prove that property and I therefore I cannot use it in the case $ n,m<0$.

b Furthermore I find myself in situations like $(-n).(-1_R)$ where $(*)$ and the shorthand $(.)$ are mixed, but to justify this  $(-n)*(-1_R)=(-n)*(-1).1_R=(-n.-1)*(1_R)=n.1_R$  I need for instance associativity and conmutativity between ring multiplication and the shorthand, which is not defined. I mean we are not in a vector space here!

**1.How do I resolve these situations and proceed?**

**2.Am I on the right track on my approach? is it really that long? Isn't there a shorter approach?**

Answer (score 1):

Proving this depends on how much you already know about $\mathbb{Z}$. I will assume you know that $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on $1$.

Clearly, a ring homomorphism $f : \mathbb{Z} \to R$ must be the unique group homomorphism such that $f(1) = 1_R$. Conversely, I claim that this unique group homomorphism is also a ring homomorphism.

The only thing that remains to be checked is that $f$ commutes with multiplication.

> Lemma: Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then let $S_m = \{n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid f(nm) = f(n) f(m)\}$. Then $S_m = \mathbb{Z}$.

Proof: we first prove that $S_m$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. This is trivial, since the maps $n \mapsto f(nm)$ and $n \mapsto f(n) f(m)$ are both group homomorphisms (you can check this as an exercise), and $S_m$ is the equalizer of these two maps.

Now we note that $1 \in S_m$. This is obvious, since $f(1) f(m) = 1_R f(m) = f(m) = f(1 \cdot m)$.

Now since $S_m$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ containing $1$, and since $\mathbb{Z}$ is the free group on $1$, it follows that $S_m = \mathbb{Z}$. $\square$

> Corollary: for all $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f(nm) = f(n) f(m)$.

Proof: for $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, note that $n \in S_m$, so $f(nm) = f(n) f(m)$. We are done. $\square$

Comment: I am not familiar with the concepts of free group nor of equalizer, but I guess this is the shorter proof, so the answer to question 2. Regarding question 1, wich was actually the main part of my question, is my approach correct? and how would I solve the situations I described?